# Batch script output unmatched to csv

Tags: batch-file, csv

I have a batch script that, amongst other things, matches a filename on one csv (which also contains other data) to the file directory and filename on another csv. What I want is for any filenames that don't match up to be output into another csv so that I know of any that aren't present on either csv. The part of the code that does that match is below:

```
dir "C:\Test\*.tif" /b /s >> "C:\Test\input3.csv"


setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

< input2.csv (
  for /F "delims=" %%a in (input3.csv) do (
  set /P line2=
  echo %%a,!line2!
)
) > input4.csv
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see the code above only merges input2.csv and input3.csv in to input4.csv, if this is the case why not just do a formula in input4.csv to match columnA (Output from input2.csv) and columnB (Output from input3.csv) ?

Excel:

```
=IF(A#=B#,"True","False")
```